metaplex umi: Failed to send transaction Error: Simulation failed. Message: Transaction signature verification failure
BACKEND:
    const wallet_pubkey = new PublicKey(wallet_pubkey_string);
    const wallet2 = Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs58.decode(wallet2_key));
    const amount = 0.5;
    
    const signer_wallet = createNoopSigner(fromWeb3JsPublicKey(wallet_pubkey));
    
    const umi = createUmi(rpcUrl);
    umi.use(mplTokenMetadata());
    umi.use(signerIdentity(signer_wallet))
    const umiMintSigner = generateSigner(umi);
    
    const nftData = {
        mint: umiMintSigner,
        isMutable: true,
        name: 'test',
        symbol: 'test',
        uri: url,
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(10,2),
        creators: creators,
        tokenOwner: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(wallet_pubkey),
    };
    const transferData = {
        destination: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(wallet2.publicKey),
        amount: sol(amount),
    };
    let transaction = await transactionBuilder()
        .add(createNft(umi, nftData))
        .add(transferSol(umi, transferData))
        .setFeePayer(signer_wallet)
        .useV0()
        .buildWithLatestBlockhash(umi);
    
    
    const web3jsVersionedTransaction = toWeb3JsTransaction(transaction);
    const web3jsVersionedTransactionSerialized = web3jsVersionedTransaction.serialize()
    const transaction_serialize_string = Buffer.from(web3jsVersionedTransactionSerialized).toString('base64');

FRONTEND:
On the frontend, the transaction is signed by the wallet wallet_pubkey.
    if (window.solana && window.solana.isPhantom) {
      try {
        const connection = new Connection(url, "confirmed");
        const transaction_array = Buffer.from(transactionBuildValue, 'base64');
        const decodedTransaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(transaction_array);
        const { blockhash } = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
        decodedTransaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
        const signedTransaction = await window.solana.signTransaction(decodedTransaction);
        const signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(signedTransaction.serialize());
        await connection.confirmTransaction(signature, 'processed');
        return { success: true, signature };
        console.log(signature);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }

I get an error when trying to confirm a transaction via wallet.
Error:
> Failed to send transaction Error: Simulation failed.  Message:
> Transaction signature verification failure.

If I don't use the string .add(createNft(umi, nftData)) then the problem doesn't occur and the code works correctly.
How to fix the problem?

update: If you are sending the transaction to be signed on the frontend,

initialize with an empty umi signer identity and the public key that's supposed to sign the transaction

umi.use(
        signerIdentity({
            publicKey: publicKey(authority),
            signTransaction: async (tx) => tx,
            signMessage: async (data) => data,
            signAllTransactions: async (txs) => txs,
        })
    );


convert to web3 js and sign with the mint

let web3JsTx = toWeb3JsTransaction(transaction);

web3JsTx.sign([Keypair.fromSecretKey(umiMintSigner.secretKey)]);

let b64EncodedTx = Buffer.from(umi.transactions.serialize(fromWeb3JsTransaction(web3JsTx)).toString("base64");


Yeah, my other problem was that in creators the verified field was set to true. This was causing an additional signature error.

you need to verify them one by one IIRC -> https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/creators

sorry, can you help with this question ? i get error when i try add updateAuthority in nftData.
